# django runserver doesn't show the starting development server message

Tags: django, server, django-settings

why in mingw64 the django manage.py runserver comand doens't output the message of starting the server but runs it anyway. Also right after i do ctrl + c and shut the server, the message is then shown. ;/

in the windows cmd it works fine anyway.. i'm just curious if anyone has any clue how to properly run this inside the bash which i'm so much more familiar with.

thanks anyway!